# Is there a point in Docker start?

Tags: docker, containers

So, is there a point in the command "start"? like in "docker start -i albineContainer".

If I do this, I can't really do anything with the albine inside the container, I would have to do a run and create another container with the "-it" command and "sh" after (or "/bin/bash", don't remember it correctly right now).

Is that how it will go most of the times? delete and rebuilt containers and do the command "-it" if you want to do stuff in them? or would it more depend on the Dockerfile, how you define the cmd.

New to Docker in general and trying to understand the basics on how to use it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Running docker run/exec with `-it` means you run the docker container **and attach an interactive terminal to it**.

Note that you can also run docker applications without attaching to them, and they will still run in the background.

Docker allows you to run a program (which can be `bash`, but does not have to be) in an isolated environment.

For example, try running the jenkins docker image: https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins.
this will create a container, without you having attach to it, and you would still be able to use it.

You **can** also attach to an existing, running container by using `docker exec -it [container_name] bash`.

You can also use `docker logs` to peek at the stdout of a certain docker container, without actually attaching to its shell interactively.

Comment: But that would mean that I would have to 'run' everytime I have to do something and specify with subcommands what I want to do, right? I really can't just create a container of an image and then use 'start' to interact with it, I have to do the 'run' with all the needed subcommands of what a I want to do.

If the image I'm creating the container with had a cmd that said "launch the bash" (I don't know how I would have to write it for the cmd to do that), then using the 'start' command would be the right call?

Comment: Im trying to not have to create and erase containers most of the time if possible. Wanting to know if creating a good Dockerfile or making a good 'run' command is the way to go, or looking things from a wrong angle. Thanks for answering, btw c:

Comment: You can run it once and then attach to it and exec bash each time you want to run a new command, try `docker exec -it [container_name] bash`

Answer (score 1):

You almost never use `docker start`.  It's only possible to use it in two unusual circumstances:

1. If you've created a container with `docker create`, then `docker start` will run the process you named there.  (But it's much more common to use `docker run` to do both things together.)
2. If you've stopped a container with `docker stop`, `docker start` will run its process again.  (But typically you'll want to `docker rm` the container once you've stopped it.)

Your question and other comments hint at using an interactive shell in an unmodified Alpine container.  Neither is a typical practice.  Usually you'll take some complete application and its dependencies and package it into an image, and `docker run` will run that complete packaged application.  Tutorials like Docker's [Build and run your image](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) go through this workflow in reasonable detail.

My general day-to-day workflow involves building and testing a program outside of Docker.  Once I believe it works, *then* I run `docker build` and `docker run`, and `docker rm` the container once I'm done.  I rarely run `docker exec`: it is a useful debugging tool but not the standard way to interact with a process.  `docker start` isn't something I really ever run.

Comment: Okay, thx for the heads up. Yeah, I was trying to get the grip around reusing containers that have the image I want to work on. Maybe it is that, to make a good Dockerfile and then run it. Thx for answering c:

Comment: A container isn't expensive and deleting and recreating it is extremely routine.  I wouldn't try to reuse containers at all.